# "makeindex" in Mac OS X (Snow Leopard)

Tags: indexing, mac, texshop

I use LaTeX on a Mac, using TeXShop. It is possible to compile an index from within the TeXShop interface, except when I have more than one index (say, people and concepts) for the same text. In this case I used to compile it from Terminal:

```
makeindex MyIndex
```

say. But since I went from Mac OS 10.5 to 10.6 (Snow Leopard), the latter does not work anymore (albeit normal, single-index compilation from within TeXShop works fine). Any idea?

Comment: This sounds like a shell path problem.  What does `which makeindex` return in Terminal?  Also, what does `echo $PATH` return?

Comment: Oh, I see. I have looked for makeindex binary and added its location (/usr/local/texlive/2008/bin/universal-darwin, to be precise) to my path. Now it works, thanks! Could I have done it in a more elegant way?

Comment: If you're using MacTeX 2008, you have a *really* old distribution.  I would strongly encourage you to update to MacTeX 2011. That being said, you don't need to add the binary itself to your path, just `/usr/texbin`. (Assuming that existed in 2008; I think it did.)

Comment: For multiple indices I usually propose to use the package **imakeidx** (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors) that automatizes the run of `makeindex`. Give it a try. But, first of all, solve the `PATH` problem.

Comment: @Alan Munn: Yes, `/usr/texbin` already existed, and now I have set it in the path. Downloading MacTex 2011 now.

Comment: @egreg: I didn't know your package: I'll certainly try it. Thanks for it, as well as for the useful stuff on your page (I am Italian too), for instance the LaTeX "horrors": I hope not to be guilty of too many of them)!

Comment: @DaG I'm currently working on a chapter of _[LaTeX and Friends](http://www.springer.com/computer/media+design/book/978-3-642-23815-4)_ that explains how to do this. The chapter, together with equivalent chapters for `windows` and `unix`) will be made freely available later this week/month on http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF. I'll make an announcement in compt.tex.text when the chapters are available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following answer is compiled from the comments, so that we can remove this question from the "unanswered" list.

The problem you are describing is characteristic of a path problem with your shell profile.  To determine whether you are able to run the `makeindex` command from the command line, you can do:

```
which makeindex
```

This should return: `/usr/texbin/makeindex`.  If it doesn't, and returns nothing, then your TeX binaries aren't being found.  (They are found by TeXShop because it sets its own path for all commands.)

To see what your path is, you can enter:

```
echo $PATH
```

This should return something  that includes `/usr/texbin`; if it doesn't you need to fix that in your `.profile` or `.bashrc` file.

If you're using MacTeX 2008, you have a *really* old distribution. I would strongly encourage you to update to MacTeX 2011.

As egreg notes, for multiple indices the package [`imakeidx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) is useful, as it automates the run of `makeindex`. (He is the author of `imakeidx`.)

Answer (score 2):

Add the line

```
% !TEX TS-program = latexmk
```

at the top of your .tex file and compile it using the LaTeX engine.  (In TeXShop `Typeset`

with `LaTeX` selected.)

The following is an example and the 3-page output.

```
% !TEX TS-program = latexmk
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multind}
\makeindex{indexA}
\makeindex{indexB}


\begin{document}

I use LaTeX on a \index{indexA}{Mac}Mac, using \index{indexB}{TeXShop}TeXShop. It is possible 
to compile an \index{indexA}{index}index from within the \index{indexB}{TeXShop}TeXShop 
interface, except when I have more than one \index{indexA}{index}index (say, people and 
concepts) for the same text. In this case I used to compile it from Terminal:

makeindex MyIndex

say. But since I went from Mac OS 10.5 to 10.6 (Snow Leopard), the latter does not work 
anymore (albeit normal, single-index compilation from within \index{indexB}{TeXShop}TeXShop 
works fine). Any idea?

\printindex{indexA}{Index A}
\printindex{indexB}{Index B}
\end{document}
```

page 1 of the output:
[image]

page2 of the output:
[image]

page3 of the output:
[image]